# What happens at the end of Clive Barker's Undying?

Tags: clive-barkers-undying

Spoiler alert!

> At the end of Clive Barker's Undying Patrick the protagonist is taken away by some robed figure in a boat after he kills the final boss.

What does this represent? How do I interpret this scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The robed figure at the end is **definitely not** Otto Keisinger. If you listen to the dialog at the end Patrick says

> The creature was a guardian. A sentinel of the gate to...somewhere. Somewhen. The Celtic warrior was just a sacrificial lid on a tomb that was never supposed to be opened.

The robed figure is the Celtic warrior who assisted in burying the Undying King if you remember the flashback / dream about it before.

**Flashback / Dream:**

[image]

**Ending:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Patrick Galloway is taken away in a boat by Otto Keisinger who mysteriously survived their battle in Oneiros. Keisinger stole Patrick's Gel'ziabar stone and left Patrick at the shore. How he survived and why he rescued Patrick is not detailed, but the game revealed that Keisinger desired the Gel'ziabar stone and that's why he took it. The ending is a bit of cliff-hanger and there were talks of sequels but the game did not sell to expectations and the plans for a sequel were scrapped.

Comment: How do you know that he is really Otto Keisinger?

Comment: Patrick recognizes him and exclaims "you" or something to similar effect and you have killed every other significant NPC in the game. According to the journal Keisinger wants the stone and the robed figure takes it. Finally the robed man's and Keisinger's faces are similar.

Comment: He is definitely not Otto Keisinger, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What if Otto Keisinger is a sentinel of the gate and has to oversee it for eternity and that's why he medled in the Covenant family in the first place. Because they started this curse as children and now Keisinger has to repair the evil that has been done.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the man who gave the stone to Patrick. Definitely not Kissinger, because he is evil and has deceived the Covenant family. And he is not the monk who buried the Celtic king. Because it happened long, long before Patrick was even born. And apparently he recognized the man.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how things work around here. This has already been covered in another answer, so if you could add some more details to help prove this (that has not already been granted) this would help improve your answer.

Comment: Username checks out. :D

Answer (score -1):

The robed figure could be [Charon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charon_%28mythology%29), the ferryman of the dead in Greek mythology.

Charon (or Kharon) carried newly deceased souls across the river Styx in the underworld. This fits with the robed figure and the boat and all the occult themed things in the game.

This may be the wrong answer though but at least it's an interpretation.

Source: Charon (Wikipedia)

Comment: Patrick did not die at the end since he says that it took months for him to regain his strength.